# Add previously deleted app without changing bundle-id

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Is there a way to add a previously deleted ios app in fabric without changing its bundle id. The same app was already added and later deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Chintan from Fabric / Firebase support
Yes, this can be done without any issues, if the app was deleted by mistake and needs to be restored with its historical data intact, reach out to support(at)fabric(dot)io and they can restore it for you.

Note: You should provide your app's bundle id / package name and associated Org name.

Answer (score 0):

> As Fabric is merged into Firebase, you need to create a new project in Firebase and then add the iOS app into it.